# Javascript to detect iPhone web browser

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to detect if a page is visited by an iPhone.

What I'm basically looking for is for a way to stop all but iPhone from viewing a specific web page.

Something like...

If Browser !=iPhone then exit;

Is this possible using Javascript?

Comment: Can I ask why?  (My Android isn't in the cool kids club?)  Many years ago, we tried allowing only certain browsers to view our pages, and we've since decided that was a terrible idea.  It's why--to this day--IE claims it's Mozilla.  Don't detect browser; feature detect.

Comment: No special reason really

Comment: For example a page with links to apple store

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("iphone") ==-1) 
  location.replace("goaway.html");
```

Comment: And if it's a jail broken iPhone running a browser other than Safari?

Comment: And what? Or a PC with safari with a fake userAgent. Or anything with JS turned off

Comment: Precisely, so do it at the server, or just put a "iPhone users click here" button on the site.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) {
   ...
}
```

Though i would recommend you to do that before the DOM is loaded, e.g. with PHP:

```
<?php
  if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone')) {

  }
?>
```

Comment: Good answer - however there is no need to match, merely to test for the existence of the `iPhone` string, so `indexOf()` is better.