# Horizontal dropdown menu to vertical stack menu for mobile

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with making my dropdown menu responsive so it goes from a horizontal menu on the desktop / tablet to a stacked vertical dropdown menu for the iphone / android.

The menu is at bankruptcycanada.com/menu4.html and the markup is

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
   <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contact a Trustee</a>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>FAQ</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='/question1.htm'>Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
         <li><a href='/Credit-Counsellors.htm'>Credit Counsellors</a></li>
         <li><a href='/how-bankruptcy-works.htm'>How Bankruptcy Works</a></li>
         <li><a href='/BankruptcySteps.ppt.mht.html'>Steps in a Bankruptcy</a></li>
         <li><a href='/personal1.htm'>Personal Bankruptcy</a></li>
         <li><a href='/business1.htm'>Business Bankruptcy</a></li>
         <li><a href='/conduct-before-filing-bankruptcy.htm'>Conduct Before Going Bankrupt</a></li>
         <li><a href='/meeting-the-trustee.htm'>Meeting the Trustee</a></li>
         <li><a href='/Bankruptcy-Myths.htm'>Bankruptcy Myths</a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='/blog.htm'>Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='/BankruptcyTermPredictor.php'>Bankruptcy Cost</a></li>
   <li><a href='/ask-a-trustee/'>Ask a Trustee</a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Proposals</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='/consumer-proposals.htm'>Consumer Proposals - Avoid Bankruptcy</a></li>
         <li><a href='/Bankruptcy-vs-Consumer-Proposals.htm'>Bankruptcy vs. Consumer Proposal</a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='/ConsumerProposalSteps.html'>Steps in a Consumer Proposal</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
      <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>Exemptions</a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='/bankruptcyexemptions.htm'>Find Out What You KEEP</a></li>
      </ul>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>After Bankruptcy</a>
      <ul>
         <li class='last'><a href='/rebuildcredit1.htm'>Credit After Bankruptcy</a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='/After-Bankruptcy-Lenders.htm'>After Bankruptcy Lenders</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='/francais.htm'>Francais</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have separate stylesheets desktop.css / tablet.css / iphone.css / phone.css.

The styles I wrote for the desktop is:

```
#cssmenu
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
#cssmenu {
  height: 37px;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  list-style: inside none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  list-style: inside none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  top: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -2px;
  z-index: 99;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a:after {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 4px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #FFF;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 19px;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a {
  background: #c00404;
  border-color: #c00404;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  z-index: 999;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > ul,
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > div {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
  background: #c00404;
  border-color: #c00404;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul,
#cssmenu ul li > div {
  display: none;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: #9C2125;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  z-index: 999;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul {
  width: 160px;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style: inside none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li > ul li a {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  font: 10pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #003d4a;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #003d4a 0%, #013273 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #003d4a), color-stop(100%, #013273));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #003d4a 0%, #013273 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #003d4a 0%, #013273 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #003d4a 0%, #013273 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #003d4a 0%, #013273 100%);
}
#cssmenu {
  border-color: #c00404;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  border-right: 1px solid #c00404;
  color: #FFF;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:after {
  border-color: #fb2f2f;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  background: #c00404;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #deb40d;
  font-weight:bold; 
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:hover:before {
  border-top: 5px solid #ffffff;
}
```

I have two issues:

1) The menu on the desktop doesn't stretch to fit across the full width of the screen; the last two items drop down a line when there is still space for them to fit. How can I fix this?

2) What changes do I need to make to the css to make it respond as mobile for the iphone.css and phone.css? Do I need to add jquery, if so what script and where?

Please help!! I would really appreciate some help with this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1) Look: `div#content` has width `798px`, `div#cssmenu` has width `auto`. `div#cssmenu` is children of `div#content`, so it will be same width as parent (`798px`). It is same and has width `798px`.

You can restructure your code a bit. You can create 1 more wrapper (outer of content), with width, which will be okay for your menu and put `div#content` into it.

2) This issue may be not as simple, as you can think. There are many articles with ways to detect `iphone` etc. Use google of find some on there, on so.com.

For example: 
http://davidwalsh.name/detect-iphone 
or this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820473/2898694
etc. you can find many examples by yourself.

But this such methods will cause some problems. What if js is turned off? Why if user will use not popular browser? Etc etc etc.

I suggest you to use mediaqueries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 600px)" href="600.css" />
```

This will load css file `600.css` for browsers which device is at least 600px width. You can add css files for more screen widths.

You can read more about this here: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/ (also, there are a video available)

Hope this will help you.

P.S.: About gadges. There are no `hover` action on gadges, so your drop down menu will not work/will not work properly. You have to think about gadgets users and find another way to show menu for them or they will be stacked on main page.